# Pod command not working after installation of cocoa pods

Tags: terminal, cocoapods, pod-install

I am using macOS Monterey 12.6.7

I installed the cocoa pods using `sudo gem install cocoapods` after that I tried to run the pod install, but its not working and saying this error.

```
Unable to locate the CocoaPods.app application bundle. Please ensure the application is available and launch it at least once.
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  pod
```

I don't understand why this error is occurring.
Kindly help me out in this situation.

**Edited**

I also tried to run

```
pod setup
```

But still same problem

[image]